# Grabbing with your index-finger and thumb - Word Search

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that describes how a person grabs a pencil or a paper with his index-finger and thumb?

Comment: *Pinch*, perhaps?

Comment: Grab means to hold something tightly and in a fast manner, you need a pencil urgently and you grab your classmate's pencil without asking. You would not grab something using your index finger and thumb. The most appropriate verb that I can come with is [**hold**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/hold) But here's a link with loads of synonyms. Enjoy! :)

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Hold-a-Pencil

Comment: Aside from grasp or hold, is there a word (or phrase) that encompasses the actual movement I described--you know, bringing the index-finger and thumb together to hold or grasp something?

Comment: Please edit and add your request *in* the actual question! :)

Comment: It actually already is in the actual question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments indicate, *hold* is the most appropriate verb when not describing the use of just the index finger and thumb.

The synonyms for hold which @Mari-LouA provided can be of use, but only when you describe the way the person is clasping, clutching, grasping, gripping, clenching, or clinging to the pencil, pen or paper. For example, "He gripped the pencil between his index finger and thumb."

Using the synonyms without the description of using the index finger and thumb would generally indicate the use of more digits or even the whole hand.